# How to remove duplicate entries from FragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a simple activity with a `BottomNavigationView`. I'm using fragments to implement the contents of the activity for the different pages.

When the user presses the back button, it's supposed to go back to the previously looked at page. The problem is, when you repeatedly switch back and forth between the pages (fragments), this entire history is recorded. Take this example:

A -> B -> A -> B -> C -> A -> C

Pressing the back button would result in the reverse, but instead I want this behaviour (I noticed it in the Instagram app):

C -> A -> B -> Exit App

So every fragment should only have one entry in the backstack. How do I do this? I do I remove the previous transactions for a fragment from the stack?

Is this at all possible using a FragmentManager? Or do I have to implement my own?

My Activity with the BottomNavigationView:

```
class ActivityOverview : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Listener for BottomNavigationView
    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                // "Home" menu item pressed
                setActiveFragment(resources.getString(R.string.tag_fragment_home))
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                // "Dashboard" menu item pressed
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_settings -> {
                // "Settings" menu item pressed
                setActiveFragment(resources.getString(R.string.tag_fragment_settings))
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview)

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
        navigation.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_home).setChecked(true)
        // Set initial fragment
        setActiveFragment(resources.getString(R.string.tag_fragment_home))
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        // > 1 so initial fragment addition isn't removed from stack
        if (fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 1) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack()
        } else {
            finish()
        }
    }

    // Update displayed fragment
    fun setActiveFragment(tag: String) {
        val fragment = if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) != null) {
            // Fragment is already initialized
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag).isVisible) {
                // Fragment is visible already, don't add another transaction
                null
            } else {
                // Fragment is not visible, add transaction
                fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
            }
        } else {
            // Fragment is not initialized yet
            when (tag) {
                resources.getString(R.string.tag_fragment_home) -> FragmentHome()
                resources.getString(R.string.tag_fragment_settings) -> FragmentSettings()
                else -> null
            }
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment, tag)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gut reaction is: every time you add a fragment, look for it in the fragment manager and remove it (with `FragmentTransaction.remove()`) if it's there. That way there's only ever one instance of a given fragment in your fragment manager and the newest ones are at the top.

Comment: @BenP. But how do I retrieve the actual transaction, not just the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I'm pretty sure it doesn't work with FragmentManager, so I created a class to implement a stack that doesn't allow duplicates:

```
class NoDuplicateStack<T> {

    val stack: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()
    val size: Int
        get() = stack.size

    // Push element onto the stack
    fun push(p: T) {
        val index = stack.indexOf(p)
        if (index != -1) {
            stack.removeAt(index)
        }
        stack.add(p)
    }

    // Pop upper element of stack
    fun pop(): T? {
        if (size > 0) {
            return stack.removeAt(stack.size - 1)
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    // Look at upper element of stack, don't pop it
    fun peek(): T? {
        if (size > 0) {
            return stack[stack.size - 1]
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

}
```

I then integrated this class into my activity:

```
class ActivityOverview : AppCompatActivity() {

    val fragmentsStack = NoDuplicateStack<String>()
    val fragmentHome = FragmentHome()
    val fragmentSettings = FragmentSettings()
    val fragmentHistory = FragmentHistory()

    // Listener for BottomNavigationView
    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (fragmentsStack.size > 1) {
            // Remove current fragment from stack
            fragmentsStack.pop()
            // Get previous fragment from stack and set it again
            val newTag = fragmentsStack.pop()
            if (newTag != null) {
                setActiveFragment(newTag)
            }
        } else {
            finish()
        }
    }

    // Update displayed fragment
    fun setActiveFragment(tag: String) {
        val fragment = when (tag) {
            resources.getString(R.string.tag_fragment_home) -> fragmentHome
            resources.getString(R.string.tag_fragment_settings) -> fragmentSettings
            resources.getString(R.string.tag_fragment_history) -> fragmentHistory
            else -> null
        }

        if (fragment != null && !fragment.isVisible) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment, tag)
                    .commit()
            fragmentsStack.push(tag)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got the same exact requirement as you have mentioned in the question. I'm trying to implement your solution, however given that I am working in java and not kotlin, I'm not able to implement the exact same logic you have used. Is it possible you could provide a java compatible solution too?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, I did this which uses the system stack

```
   val totalFragments = supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount

            if (totalFragments != 0) {
                val removed = supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(totalFragments - 1)
                poppedFragments.add(removed.name!!)

                for (idx in totalFragments - 1  downTo 0) {
                    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(idx)
                    if (!poppedFragments.contains(fragment.name)) {
                        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(fragment.name, 0)
                        return
                    }
                }

                finish()
                return
            }

            super.onBackPressed()
```

and then added this while launching the fragment

```
    if (poppedFragments.contains(tag)) {
            poppedFragments.remove(tag)
        }
```